# Understanding the output of cut -f

Tags: linux, shell-script, echo, cut

Thank you for your patience I am new to linux and I wanted some help understanding how I can parse the output of the cut command.

So, currently I have a variable

`x=$(discover nginx --human=nood | cut -f1,6)`

So my output to `echo "$x` is a list of like

> instanceID IPAddress

In my program I want to run a for loop over each row of x and extract the first and the second variables separately. 
Eg: if it was an array a[0] = instanceID and a[1]= IPAdderess

Please can someone guide me how to extract the elements separately.
I know that I can run a loop in `$x` and do a cut within that but I am looking to understand if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you don't need to store the data in a variable at all, a loop over the output of `discover` will do:

```bash
discover nginx --human=nood | cut -f 1,6 |
while read -r instanceID IPAddress; do
    # Use "$instanceID" and "$IPAddress" here
done
```

Alternatively, in `bash` or a shell that understands process substitutions (`<( ... )`):

```bash
while read -r instanceID IPAddress; do
    # Use "$instanceID" and "$IPAddress" here
done < <( discover nginx --human=nood | cut -f 1,6 )
```

The difference between these two is only visible if you want to carry the values of some variable *out of the loop*.  In the first example, the loop will run in a subshell and you would therefore not be use any values of variables that set inside the loop *after* the loop (they exists in their own local environment).

In the second example, no subshells are involved (except for the one that runs the process substitution with `discover` and `cut`), so values of variables are accessible after the loop.

Comment: I am trying to write a bash script that uses a variable that already has the x=$( discover nginx --human=nood).

When I try ``` "$x" |cut -f1,6 | while ...```  I get an error of command not found